# FM Receiver and Delay simulation GNU Radio - Issue with modifying Delay block in run-time

Tags: gnuradio

I'm actually doing a FM receiver with an antenna linked to an USRP N210 and demodulate it.

I have two channel: one with delay and one without.

I set my delay in seconds (`samp_rate*sec`) and everything is working fine, I hear both  the delayed signal and the "real" time signal. I can set the variable "sec" to 10,20 to have a 10 or 20 sec delay, it work well i hear both signal.

I'd like to increase the delay when the simulation is running, so instead of setting "sec" as a variable I did a range block  to increase second per second the delay (it start with 1 second delay).

The thing is that it work well until sec = 3, when I reach  this point both signal stopped like they've frozen, can't hear them anymore even if I move the range sec cursor to 1,2 or anything (note that GNU radio isn't freezing)...I thought maybe that was due to "*users have had issues when delaying by very large numbers*" on the delay's [wiki](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Delay) but when I'm setting the delay to 10, 20 secs before starting my simulation, the delay work perfectly.

But each times I want to increase the delay during the simulation , at the third iteration (sec=3) both signal are gone, gnuradio isn't freezing or bugging since I can keep moving the cursor of the range block, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong ?

My graph is below.

[image]